# Is there any DLL or DLL like concept in Android?

Tags: android, dll

1. We know that we can use a concept "Java Package", but I just wanted to
   know whether Android has provided a DLL or DLL like concept where we can write a 
   most of the functionality.
2. Or can we use *Activity* for serving a purpose of DLL.

Is there any concept like DLL on Android OS? Can we develop a DLL for better modularization and other benefits on Android?

Thanks and Regards,
Prashant.

Comment: Using [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html#overview) you can create native code libraries from C/C++ code.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think the OP is asking about Java libraries.

Comment: Thanks Now i am near to conclusion of above doubt just few things remains - 
1. Definitely we can use Android NDK at Library layer at Android Architecture, which serves DLL purpose. Now I wanted to know that can we do at Application Layer using some concept.

2. I have read in Android document that, we can use Activity which services required dedicated facility.

Comment: .so files at the native layer, .jar files at the java layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are specifically looking for DLL. What I realize is that you need something like a library for code reuse. Java Packages (jar files) serve the same purpose of modularization.

If you want to code in C++ look into [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html#overview) and create a .so file (Linux equivalent for DLL)

May be you are looking for some sort of content provider that can help you with sharing across applications.

Comment: Yes even i am thinking the same as you. And I am not looking exactly for DLL but similar concept using which i can take an advantages of performance, memory utilization and reuse of code. Also Android NDK is at Library Layer. I want at Application Layer of Android Architecture.