# Managing the project structure of larger and more complex apps

Tags: java, android, module, package

This is a bit of a basic question/s and pertains to project structure. It's just a basic concept I have missed in android. (as a result of being self taught).

With an app that has many classes, activities and fragments, it's becoming busy in both the java and res folders.

I am unsure what is the best way to proceed with managing larger projects.

For instance, if I have a various sections, bluetooth, wifi, gps, etc.  And for many of these they are reusable code "packages" or "modules" (I am not sure of  the correct word).

How should I go about formatting my project?
Using packages?
Is there a dll concept equivalent?

There is this question here:
[Is there any DLL or DLL like concept in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651161/is-there-any-dll-or-dll-like-concept-in-android), but it doesn't really help clarify this issue for me.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I go about formatting my project?

It depends on your needs. If you want to move some part of logic to a library, you can do that by creating an android library project. See **Library Module** section: https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

> Is there a dll concept equivalent?

If you want to have a compiled version of that library project (like DLL) you can generate a `.jar` file. Refer this link: [How to create jar for Android Library Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063826/how-to-create-jar-for-android-library-project)

So, you can link android library project directly, or, compile it first, and then include as a `.jar` file.